# JSONPatch escape slash '/' from JSONPatch+JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, json-patch, http-patch

I've below JSON and I wanted to update few fields from it

```
{
        "process": "my-process",
        "pod": "some-pod",
        "org": "some-org",
        "config": {
            "version": "436_601_83.0.0",
            "path": "companyName/ccg",
            "description": "update the version",
            "dependencies": null
        }
}
```

using postman PATCH API call with below JSONPatch payload API is working fine

```
[
    {
        "path": "/config/version",
        "op": "replace",
        "value": "436_605_83.0.0"
    },
    {
        "path": "/config/description",
        "op": "replace",
        "value": "foo bar"
    }
]
```

But, I want to implement same using Java .. I tried

```
JsonPatch jsonPatch = new JsonPatch(
                        Arrays.asList(               
                           new ReplaceOperation(JsonPointer.of("/config/version"),
                              new TextNode("436_605_83.0.0"))
                        )
                );
```

It evaluates to :

```
[{"op":"replace","path":"/~1config~1version","value":"436_605_83.0.0"}]
```

This doc mentioned that http://jsonpatch.com/#json-pointer we MUST use escape the characters with `~0` and `~1` but no luck yet, I escaped `/` using `~1` i.e. `"~1config~1version"` but it evaluates to `"/~01config~01version"`

Comment: 1) Which programming language is this? 2) Depending on 1, from where did you get `JsonPointer`?

Comment: I'm trying using Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `JsonPointer` definition. Please, try something like that instead:

```java
JsonPatch jsonPatch = new JsonPatch(
  Arrays.asList(               
    new ReplaceOperation(
      // Note we should provide the different paths tokens here
      JsonPointer.of("config", "version"),
      new TextNode("436_605_83.0.0")
    )
  )
);
```

Or, equivalently:

```java
JsonPatch jsonPatch = new JsonPatch(
  Arrays.asList(               
    new ReplaceOperation(
      // Create the JsonPointer with the full path
      new JsonPointer("/config/version"),
      new TextNode("436_605_83.0.0")
    )
  )
);
```

Please, see [this test](https://github.com/java-json-tools/jackson-coreutils/blob/549007e035a878b9cb5cc7f51beeca56817c731c/src/test/java/com/github/fge/jackson/jsonpointer/JsonPointerTest.java#L158-L179), it provides guidance about how to tactically build `JsonPointer`s and the meaning of escaping reserved chars.

Comment: You are welcome @SwapnilKotwal. I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful